# How to extract a file within a folder within a zip

Tags: r, unzip

I downloaded a zip file (20000101[1].zip) with following subfolder structure

```
\home\ftp\pub\account\lmp\20010101.csv.
```

Do yo guys have any idea how to extract the file `20010101.csv`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to read the `csv` without extracting it (sometimes it's quite useful), assuming eg a folders structure like this one

```
l@np350v5c:~$ zipinfo foo.zip 
Archive:  foo.zip
Zip file size: 481 bytes, number of entries: 3
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 14-May-27 22:52 foo/
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 14-May-27 22:52 foo/bar/
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx       21 tx stor 14-May-27 22:52 foo/bar/asd.csv
3 files, 21 bytes uncompressed, 21 bytes compressed:  0.0%
```

... you can try `unz` which creates a connection to a file inside a `.zip` file

```
con <- unz(description="foo.zip", filename="foo/bar/asd.csv")
db <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
```

HTH, Luca

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still works if you simplify it to db <-read.csv(unz(description="foo.zip", filename="foo/bar/asd.csv"))